# Android x86 version 7.1 xposed is bootlooping

Tags: android-x86, xposed-framework

### Hey!

After trying to install Xposed framework on every version of Android x86 I found out that Android x86 version 7.1 is the only version that xposed is "bootlooping" (r1 & r2 & rc). Is anyone else encountered such thing?

I tried to install Xposed in two different ways that both of them worked on the other versions of Android x86 (4.4, 6.0, 8.1):

1. flash the Xposed zip from the terminal (unzipping the zip, giving permission to all folders and running **sh META-INF/com/.../flash-script.sh**)
2. Installing via the install option in the XposedInstaller APK

as I already wrote, this two ways of installation worked perfectly on versions 4.4, 6.0 and 8.1 of Android x86 project but not on 7.1.

Hopefully someone else in here encountered this problem of the bootlooping on Android x86 version 7.1 as well and might have a solution.

Thanks.